# A question on equipotency of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $A$ and $B$ be two different sets with the same cardinality. Then what can we say (true or false) about the statement: " corresponding to every subset $X$ of $A$ , there exist a subset $Y$ of $B$ such that $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality." ?

Comment: We can say it is false, but we'd be lying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, then whenever $X\subseteq A$, the restriction of $f$ to $X$ is a bijection with $f[X]$.

Comment: Ah $\space$,got it.